# Using Zend_Auth in Pimcore

Tags: zend-auth, pimcore

Im new to Pimcore and I'm trying to use Zend Auth with pimcore objects. I assume this is a wise approach and it seems more or less logical to me. I've done the initial setup of the object within pimcore itself. Now I'm trying to work out how to connect it to zend auth, that is, for example when I extend zend auth and have my own login function, how do i check if the login is valid in my object?

Does someone have a guide that I could use on this perhaps? otherwise if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great

Jason

Comment: Do you want to use a custom login adapter to the pimcore backend or is the authentication for your application?

Comment: The authentication is for my application. It doesn't need to tie in with the pimcore backend :)

Comment: And in the view there you display your object data you want to check if the user is logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this guide: http://www.pimcore.org/forum/discussion/419/zend_auth_adapter-for-pimcore-objects , it worked well for me.

**UPDATE:** The link above has been taken away, so laying out the full answer here:

First, you need to put [ObjectAdapter.php](http://pastebin.com/tgdXpx3s) in website/lib/Website/Auth/ObjectAdapter.php .

Then, this is how you login your user (use as you prefer, for example in your controller init function):

```
$authAdapter = new Website_Auth_ObjectAdapter('Object_Users', 'o_key', 'password', '/users/'); 
// The parameters are 1. object you keep your users in, 2. the field that contains their username (I use o_key which is the name of the object itself, to keep unique usernames without fuzz), and 3. the password field in the user object.

// Setup auth adapter
$authAdapter->setIdentity($username)->setCredential($password); 

$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance(); 

// Authenticate 
$result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter); 
if ($result->isValid()) {
    // Login successful
} else {
    // Login failed
}
```

To check for a login-session, use:

```
$this->auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if ($this->auth->hasIdentity()) { 
    // We have a login session (user is logged in)
    $userObject = $this->auth->getIdentity();
}
```

To kill a session:

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->clearIdentity();
```